# How to correct aspect ratio of tiled map rendering in libgdx?

Tags: android, libgdx, tiled

First of all, some explanation of situation.

Init tiled map code:

```
map = new TmxMapLoader().load("maps/map.tmx");
mapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, 1f / 32f);
```

Rendering code:

```
mapRenderer.setView(cam);
mapRenderer.render();
```

The problem. I have square map and non-square screen. Map fills whole screen. Because of that map scales incorrectly (32x32 cells transform to 32x40 cells according to X and Y scaling of screen). How can I render map without filling whole screen?

Comment: We need to see your camera setup. My guess is that your camera viewport is not defined properly.

Comment: My camera is:

cam = new OrthographicCamera(MyWorld.CAMERA_WIDTH, MyWorld.CAMERA_HEIGHT);

Comment: And the values of `MyWorld.CAMERA_WIDTH` and `MyWorld.CAMERA_HEIGHT` are?

Comment: As official site says, MyWorld.CAMERA_WIDTH, MyWorld.CAMERA_HEIGHT parses related to screen dimensions.
In my case CAMERA_WIDTH = CAMERA_HEIGHT = 10. 10 is the count of cells in an row of tiledmap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments on the question...

You are using a square camera on a non-square screen and ignoring the aspect ratio. To take into account the aspect ratio, do something like this:

```
float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

MyWorld.CAMERA_HEIGHT = 10;  // Fill the height of the screen
MyWorld.CAMERA_WIDTH  = 10 * (w / h); // Account for the aspect ratio

camera = new OrthographicCamera(MyWorld.CAMERA_WIDTH, MyWorld.CAMERA_HEIGHT);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But what about Stage? Can I use "new MyWorld(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(),...)"?
Or should I init square stage?

MyWorld extends Stage

Comment: Your Stage can use the actual screen dimensions if you like. You would probably not want a square Stage either.